# Click in Link from react-router not changing the user profile content

Tags: reactjs, react-router

If I am in `/josh` profile and click to go to `/marie` profile the page will not change, I'll continue in josh profile, only the url will be marie. any ideas why?

I importe profile and react-router-dom

```
import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from '../../containers/Profile/Profile'; //this.props.match.params.user
```

I have this route:

```
<Route path="/:user" component={Profile} />
```

I call another profile like this:

```
<li><Link to={"/"+user} onClick={props.closed}>Profile</Link></li>
```

+user is another username to open the profile.

Any ideas how can I change profile when I click to go to another one?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you're experiencing is the normal behavior of React Router.

The code you wrote above says to render the component `Profile` when any route matches `/:user`. When you change routes to from `/josh` to `/marie`, it actually still matches the `Profile` component so that's why it seems like nothing is happening.

However, if you look into the props of your `Profile`, you'll notice that there is a value in there that's changing based on your links and your routes.

```js
props.match.params.user
```

If you want to "go to another profile", you simply have to react to the chaning incoming props inside of you profile component.

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM;
const { MemoryRouter, Route, Link } = ReactRouterDOM;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>My App</header>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/josh">Josh</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/marie">Marie</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <main>
        <Route component={Profile} path="/:user" />
      </main>
    </div>
   );
}

function Profile(props) {
  return <div>{props.match.params.user}'s Profile</div>
}

render(<MemoryRouter><App /></MemoryRouter>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.1.2/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```